# ImageViews in Android ListView are Showing Previously Loaded Images

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-imageview

I have an android `ListView` which uses an `AsyncTask` to download a different image for each `ListViewItem`. Each image gets added to an `ArrayList<Bitmap>` the first time it is downloaded and is accessed from the `ArrayList<Bitmap>` each time after that.

If I slowly scroll through the `ListView`, each image loads as expected, but if I start scrolling faster, the visible `ListViewItems`, which have not yet downloaded their images, start to display images from items that have already scrolled off the top of the screen.

Eventually everything syncs up and the images update via the `onPostExecution` call, but what is going wrong / how can I prevent the images from previous items from appearing in the lower items in the `ListView` ?

Here's the trimmed down code:

```
private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(500); 


@Override
public View getItemView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    View itemView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            itemView = getInflater().inflate(ITEM_LAYOUT, parent, false);
        } else {
            itemView = convertView;
        }

        final ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.app_component_joblistitemview_logo);

        if (bitmapArray.size()>position && bitmapArray.get(position)!=null) {
            // Item exists at bitmapArray[position], use it
            Log.i("JobListView","Setting Existing for Position:"+position);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray.get(position));
        } else {
            // Have not downloaded this ListView[position] logo yet        
            bitmapArray.add(position,null); // add temporary null value until the image is downloaded
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(null);
            new DownloadImageTask().execute(logo.getLogoUUID(), mImageView, position);
        }

        return itemView;
    }


    // This AsyncTask downloads an image / logo from a specified URL and then updates the specified ImageView
    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

        ImageView imageView;
        Integer listViewPosition;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
            String urlString = "http://www.myimages.com/something/"+params[0].toString();

            this.imageView = (ImageView)params[1];
            this.listViewPosition = (Integer)params[2];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                bitmapArray.set(listViewPosition,myBitmap);
                return myBitmap;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log exception
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: writeing a good/working image loader is not a peace of cake ... better use one of already written ... next problem which you will face is memory managment... ArrayList<Bitmap> surely will cause OOE sonner or later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else {
        // other methods, then set tag and run task
        mImageView.setTag(logo.getLogoUUID());
        new DownloadImageTask().execute(logo.getLogoUUID(), mImageView, position);
    }
```

and

```
int uuid=-1;

protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
        uuid=params[0];
        //other methods
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    //if tag exists check validity
    if(imageView.getTag()==null && imageView.getTag().equals(uuid))
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
}
```

lets assume you have 2 pictures - first 10px square, second FHD. when your item needs FHD bitmap Downloader starts downloading, obvius. when you still scrolling and this item is "scrolled out" it apperas (as recycled/convert view) below (or above, depends on scroll direction). then you are setting download 10px bitmap which is ofc much faster. 10 px is set, but previously asynctask downloading fhd picture is still running and still keeps reference to imageView. so when fhd is downloaded it will replace this 10 px. for workaround you might set any identyfying param, your "uuid" is probably perfect for this

how listView and adapter works you may read [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) and [here](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) - check what is `convertView` in method `getView` and you might use ViewHolder pattern

PS. I see some null pointers in your code, because of cleaning? example:

```
View itemView;
final ImageView mImageView = //itemView is just created, findViewById will throw NPE
    (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.app_component_joblistitemview_logo);
```

Comment: Ok. I get what you are saying. Why doesn't it keep track of which `ListItem` / `ImageView` each `AsyncTask` is referring to? Doesn't each `ListItem` create its own `ImageView` object that is distinct?

Comment: yes, it might, but for performance purposes you should recycle your views (using convertView nad ViewHolder pattern). then you have to do downloading like I said. you've cleared a bit your `getItemView` method, I've spot e.g. null pointer (see edit), so I don't really know how do you create this ImageViews

Comment: ItemView gets defined, I updated the code to show this.

Comment: check your line `itemView = convertView;` - after this you are getting ImageView. this ImageView is the same object which disapear from screen ("scrolled out"), so previously stared AsyncTask keeps reference to this. ListView is creating only few listItem views to fill screen and when you scrolling one item disappears and appears as new from opposite side - read these two links linked in my answer